# Testing backbone views with jasmine

Tags: backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to test my backbone views with jasmine. I use underscore library to generate templates for the backbone views.

For testing purposes I use 
jasmine
jasmine-jquery

I am unable to load the fixtures in the jasmine tests as the views have embeded ruby. Here is my code

Backbone view

```
AlbumView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#album-template').html()),
    render: function() {
        $('#albums').append(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    }
});
```

This view uses the following template

Album template album_template.html.erb

```
<script type="text/html" id="album-template">
  <a href="<%%= url %>" class="album <%%= is_owner %>">
        <%% if (viewable) { %>
            <span class="album-cover">
                <span class="photo" style="background-image:url('<%%= small_thumbnail_url %>'); width: 160px; height: 160px;">
                    <span class="glossy-overlay"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <%% } %>
            <h3><%%= name %></h3>
            <p>
                <%%= number_of_photos %>
            </p>
    </a>
</script>
```

Backbone model

```
var Album = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.view = new AlbumView({model: this});
    },
    render: function() {
        this.view.render();
    }
});
```

Jasmine test - album_spec.js

```
describe('Album view', function(){

    beforeEach(function() {

        var album = new Album({
            "name": "Photo Stream",
             "url": "/albums/1",
            "id": "2",
            "number_of_photos": "172 Photos",
            "small_thumbnail_url": "/assets/sections/albums/covers/auto.png",
            "viewable": true,
            "is_owner": "owner"
        });

        loadFixtures('albums_fixture.html');

        this.view = new AlbumView();
        this.view.model = album;
        // loadFixtures('albums_fixture.html');

    });

    describe("Rendering", function() {

        it ("produces the correct HTML", function() {

            this.view.render();

            expect($("#albums")).toExist();
            expect(this.view.template).toBeDefined();

        });

    });

});
```

This spec loads the following fixture - album_fixture.html

```
<div id="albums"> </div>

<script type="text/html" id="album-template">
  <a href="<%%= url %>" class="album <%%= is_owner %>">
        <%% if (viewable) { %>
            <span class="album-cover">
                <span class="photo" style="background-image:url('<%%= small_thumbnail_url %>'); width: 160px; height: 160px;">
                    <span class="glossy-overlay"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <%% } %>
            <h3><%%= name %></h3>
            <p>
                <%%= number_of_photos %>
            </p>
    </a>
</script>
```

This test is failing at

expect(this.view.template).toBeDefined();

The fixtures is loading as this test passes expect($("#albums")).toExist();

My question is how can I load fixtures that have views with embedded ruby? I was able to successfully test the models and collections but I am having trouble testing the views.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
template: _.template($('#album-template').html())
```

in your `AlbumView` is going to be executed when that script file is loaded into the page. Since the fixture doesn't get added to the page until the spec starts to execute, the `album-template` script tag hasn't been added to the DOM yet.

If you rewrote your `template` attribute to be a method that returned the result of calling `_.template` then it wouldn't look for the script tag until you actually tried to invoke the template. This could look something like:

```
AlbumView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: function() {
        return _.template($('#album-template').html());
    },
    render: function() {
        $('#albums').append(this.template()(this.model.attributes));
    }
});
```

Granted, this is kinda gross. The other option would be to set up the underscore template as an asset served by the asset pipeline and have jasmine-gem include it into the page before you load your views.